# Getting current user after button click

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'd like to get the current user of my app script after a button click. I know that you have to use

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

but I do not know how to call gs files to the html since it errors and says "Session" is not defined.

Thanks!

edit:
I have made the code work.

```
function clickker(){
  google.script.run.testFunction();
  console.log("testsomething")
  }

(test function)
function  testFunction(){
return console.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

The console says

```
Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
```

How do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might find [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a useful resource in editing this question, and asking other questions in the future. In this case, keep in mind that Google Apps Script executes *on the server*, and the javascript/html executes *on the browser*. That is, your browser must communicate with the server to get the result of `....getEmail()`, hence the messages on net state--and any of your Apps Script code will be reflected on the server, not the browser (i.e., `console.log()` will go to Stackdriver, not your browser's console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Google Apps Script

```
function getUser() {
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

JavaScript

```
function getUser() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
    document.getElementById('userdiv').innerHTML=user;
  })
  .getUser();
}
```

html for button:

```
<input type="button" value="Get User" onClick="getUser();" />
```

[Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: I want to do this action after clicking a button. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure you can add a button as shown above into your html